# IIS502.5 Error in browser title - .NET Core application fails to execute - Suspect SDK mapping issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I am not able to run my application from `VisualStudio`.

**Experience**: Browser appears for a few seconds and closes. The browser shows the `title` as "IIS502.5 Error" before getting close. I suspect `.NET Core` runtime or SDK issue.

My application `*.csproj` has below the property

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
```

It has `nuget` packages

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="2.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.1" />
```

The command `dotnet --info` shows below information

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.592]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


C:\Users\blackpanter\dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
Version:   3.0.100
Commit:    04339c3a26

Runtime Environment:
OS Name:     Windows
OS Version:  10.0.18362
OS Platform: Windows
RID:         win10-x64
Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100\

Host (useful for support):
Version: 3.1.1
Commit:  a1388f194c

.NET Core SDKs installed:
2.1.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.509 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.607 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.1.803 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.110 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
2.2.207 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
3.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.14 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.8 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

Troubleshooting

```
  IMPORTANT: This report might contain confidential information. Mask such 
  before sharing to others.
  -----
  System Time: 1/17/2020 6:23:43 PM
  Processor Architecture: AMD64
  OS: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.18362.0
  Server Type: IIS Express
```

> ASP.NET Core module is not installed as part of IIS. Please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle for more details.

So, I have installed hosting bundle from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-3.1.1-windows-hosting-bundle-installer

But no luck :(

Comment: Run some diagnostics to rule out common issues, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: updated question after troubleshooting.

Comment: After installing ASP.NET Core module you can re-run the diagnostics.

Comment: Could you please tell me which version of your visual studio? Have you tried to install the asp.NET core by using the visual studio installer?